# Problem installing libgcc from gcc source

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I was trying to build & install GCC cross-compiler for arm-none-eabi, and got this error after running `make install-target-libgcc`, and I got this:

```
dingus@DingusPC:~/src/build-gcc$ make install-target-libgcc
/bin/bash ../gcc-11.2.0/mkinstalldirs /home/dingus/opt/gcc /home/dingus/opt/gcc
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dingus/src/build-gcc/arm-none-eabi/libgcc'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dingus/src/build-gcc/arm-none-eabi/libgcc'
make: *** [Makefile:13220: install-target-libgcc] Error 2
```

The full list of commands I run is:

```
mkdir build-gcc
cd build-gcc
../gcc-11.2.0/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c --without-headers
make all-gcc
make all-target-libgcc
make install-gcc
make install-target-libgcc
```

$PREFIX is set to `/home/dingus/opt/gcc`, and $TARGET is `arm-none-eabi`
Oddly enough, I have built it for `i686-elf` multiple times with no problem.
I was following a guide from https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: I'm not sure how, but I fixed it. The only thing I changed was I built BINUTILS and GCC to the same install directory, which I didn't when the error occurred.